# Photoshop script - suppressWarnings, disable error dialogs

Tags: scripting, photoshop, jsx

I have a script.jsx for photoshop, that exports some stuff from many PSD files. Sometimes (1 in 20 files), upon opening the psd file, the following dialog shows up:

```
var fileToOpen = new File(...);
open(fileToOpen);
```

[image: annoying dialog]

I'm running this script on hundreds of files, and I need it to somehow ignore those dialogs. "Keep layers" would be ok, but in general, anything that will prevent the dialog will help.

I've found in a manual the option suppressWarnings, but it is only available to `PdfOpenOptions` or `PhotoshopSaveOptions` - there is no such thing as `PsdOpenOptions` or `PhotoshopLoadOptions`, neither does simple object `{suppressWarnings: true}` work. I have even tried adding `displayDialogs = DialogModes.NO` but that doesn't help either.

Is there a way to prevent this dialog? (ie. stop it from blocking the script's execution)

Answer (score 1):

try `try catch` construction. If this does not help, then set the user interaction (though this may be cumbersome):
https://forums.adobe.com/thread/289239?tstart=0

Example:

```
app.scriptPreferences.userInteractionLevel = UserInteractionLevels.neverInteract;
var fileToOpen = new File(...);
open(fileToOpen);
app.scriptPreferences.userInteractionLevel = UserInteractionLevels.interactWithAll;
```